# Create customized table with dynamic 'Add', 'Edit' & 'Remove' actions with SilverStripe

Tags: javascript, silverstripe, tabular

Is there any approach to implement a table field where accommodate data entries along with 'Edit' and 'Delete' buttons (actions), in the meantime, the user is able to add a new row onto the table by using SilverStripe.

For example, there is a table showing on the home page of a website, and the user is free to add any date entry to that table and then saved to DB via the controller.

I believe Javascript&html&css will be involved but how can I combine them together? Is there an existing field type to achieve that or I need to create a field type from ground?

It does not about add this kind of table in the CMS ... Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Lots of editable table scripts around. The editing in page is managed by html and javascript. Updates are most often handled by ajax (XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for the responding. The point is how can it be implemented with SilverStripe. We need to create the field from SilverStripe side.

Comment: Like most frameworks I'm sure the docs provide approaches for setting up controllers/routes to handle ajax requests and connect to db

Comment: You should take a look at GridField tutorials

Comment: @Frank.W https://github.com/webbuilders-group/silverstripe-frontendgridfield might be worth a look when you're on SilverStripe V3